# Vue i18n not loading locales json files

Tags: i18next

Something has changed (I wish I knew what) which has broken my installation of i18n in a Vue project. The result is that the locales json files will not load.

In the \src\i18n.js file the correct json file is located but **locales(key).default** returns **undefined**, even though the file exists and correct.

The console errors such as:

> [intlify] Not found 'nav.home' key in 'en' locale messages.

refers to esm-bundler. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

I reinstalled package and it worked. It requires intlify in order to work with JSON files. Hope it helped

Comment: He already seems to have intlify installed so this wouldn't really fix much